# Akka SourceQueue to send list elements

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-stream

I have a `List[String]` and a `Source.queue`. I would like to offer this queue string elements after some interval of time. Something like this :

```
val data : List[String] = ""
val tick = Source.tick(0 second, 1 second, "tick")
tick.runForeach(t => queue.offer(data(??))
```

Can someone help me out?

Edit : I have found a way but looking for more elegant way

```
val tick = Source.tick(0 second, 2 second, "tick").zipWithIndex.limit(data.length)

tick.runForeach(t => {
  queue.offer(data(t._2.toInt))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send elements from the `List[String]` to the queue in specific time intervals for each element, use [`Source#delay`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#delay(of:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,strategy:akka.stream.DelayOverflowStrategy):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]) in the following manner:

```
val data: List[String] = ???

Source(data)
  .delay(2.seconds, DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .withAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(1, 1))
  .mapAsync(1)(x => queue.offer(x))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Set the input buffer size to one with `withAttributes` because the default value is 16, and use `DelayOverflowStrategy.backpressure`. Also, use `mapAsync` since the `offer` method returns a `Future`.

Alternatively, use [`Source#throttle`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#throttle(elements:Int,per:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maximumBurst:Int,mode:akka.stream.ThrottleMode):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]):

```
Source(data)
  .throttle(1, 2.seconds, 1, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
  .mapAsync(1)(x => queue.offer(x))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: This one is sending all the elements at once to the queue after delay of `1 second` but I want to maintain some time interval between elements of the list.
Something like below works good for me but looking for more elegant way
    
`val tick = Source.tick(0 second, 2 second, "tick").zipWithIndex.limit(randomString.length)`
 `tick.runForeach(t => {
      queue.offer(randomString(t._2.toInt))
    })`

Comment: @user3810264: Updated.